# Swift IOS 10 Firebase Push Notification

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios10

> Hello there I receive notifications on iOS 9 but not on devices with
>   iOS 10 installed. What could be the problem?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate ,FIRMessagingDelegate {

    public func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 50.0/255, green: 150.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        //create the notificationCenter
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }


        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FIRApp.configure()

        return true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        var token = ""
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
        }
        print("Registration succeeded! Token: ", token)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Registration failed!")
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            self.saveContext()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }



    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
         */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "IndirimiKovala")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    // Firebase notification received
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
        print("Handle push from foreground\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

        let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
        let d : [String : Any] = dict["alert"] as! [String : Any]
        let body : String = d["body"] as! String
        let title : String = d["title"] as! String
        print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")
        self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: title,message:body,buttonTitle:"ok",window:self.window!)

    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
        print("Handle push from background or closed\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    }

    func showAlertAppDelegate(title: String,message : String,buttonTitle: String,window: UIWindow){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

> 2017-08-02 00:30:44.172 Indirimi Kovala[8086] 
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003016] Firebase Analytics App Delegate
>   Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the
>   methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h. 2017-08-02 00:30:44.295:
>    FIRMessaging library version 1.2.2 2017-08-02
>   00:30:44.299 Indirimi Kovala[8086:863218] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver
>   initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL 2017-08-02 00:30:44.331
>   Indirimi Kovala[8086]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007]
>   Firebase Analytics v.3700000 started 2017-08-02 00:30:44.333 Indirimi
>   Kovala[8086]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable
>   debug logging set the following application argument:
>   -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ) Registration failed! 2017-08-02 00:30:44.389 [8086] 
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not
>   currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more
>   at 2017-08-02 00:30:44.402 Indirimi Kovala[8086]
>    [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the App Delegate method: 
[`application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application)

This will get called when app is not in the foreground.

---

You are currently implementing:

`userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive ...`
but this one works when the app is in the foreground only.

Answer (score 0):

Please implement below two methods

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping(UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```